# Creating Dictionaries from XML Data in Python (with xml.etree.ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having similar difficulties to the one posed in [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663322/creating-dictionary-from-xml-file), except the solution provided isn't working with my version of the problem.

With this sample XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <value>789</value>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>ABC</name>
        <value>123</value>
    </element>
</root>
```

My goal is to obtain a dictionary with the keys XYZ,ABC and the corresponding values 789,123. In other words, it should output the same as:

```
dict(XYZ=789,ABC=123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `element` tags, and their `name`, `value` children using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) and [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) methods:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>>
>>> root = ET.fromstring('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <root>
...     <element>
...         <name>XYZ</name>
...         <value>789</value>
...     </element>
...     <element>
...         <name>ABC</name>
...         <value>123</value>
...     </element>
... </root>
... ''')
>>> {e.find('name').text: e.find('value').text for e in root.findall('element')}
{'XYZ': '789', 'ABC': '123'}
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another try may be using `xpath` and `lxml.etree`.

```
from lxml import etree

s="""<root>
    <element>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <value>789</value>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>ABC</name>
        <value>123</value>
    </element>
</root>"""
tree = etree.fromstring(s)
data = [(i.xpath("./name//text()")[0],i.xpath("./value//text()")[0]) for i in tree.xpath("//element")]
print {k:v for k,v in data}
```

Output-

```
{'XYZ': '789', 'ABC': '123'}
```